# $D$ is Dense set in Real line $\mathbb{R}$ and connected.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $D\subset \mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and also connected. Must $D=\mathbb{R}$? Explain with proof.

Since $D$ is a dense subset in $\mathbb{R}$, $\overline{D} = \mathbb{R}$. I am stuck after this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $x \notin D$, then $D = (D\cap (-\infty,x)) \cup (D \cap (x,\infty))$.

Answer (score 0):

A connected set in $\Bbb R$ (or any LOTS) must be order convex ($\forall x,y \in D:\forall z: x < z < y \implies z \in D$). A dense set is unbounded on two sides, which in combination with order-convexity implies it equals $\Bbb R$: for any $x \in \Bbb R$ there must be some $x_1 \in D, x_2 \in D$ with $x_1 < x < x_2$ (to intersect the open sets $(x,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,x)$) etc.